# How to enable KVM paramters such as enable_apicv?

Tags: linux-kvm

In numerous guides (such as [this one](https://docs.kernel.org/virt/kvm/x86/running-nested-guests.html)), I've seen that running `$ cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/enable_apicv` should return `Y`, but for me it returns `N`.

But this guide doesn't tell how to fix it. How do I actually enable apicv?

According to [this datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/content-details/631121/11th-generation-intel-core-processor-datasheet-volume-1-of-2.html?wapkw=11th%20generation%20intel%20core%20i7%20processors) from intel's website, my CPU (11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7) should support it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.